# Just out of curiousty, can moderators ever deselect a wrongly selected answer?

Tags: discussion

If the author of a question ever selected an answer that was clearly wrong can a moderator ever de-select the wrong answer?

Comment: This is why all other users can upvote, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators cannnot change the accepted answer, but they can delete an accepted answer. In general, choosing the accepted answer is the decision of the user asking the question alone.